# What is the JSON format to pass POINT data type values?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot, mysql-spatial

I am using Java, Spring boot, MySQL and data JPA. Check my code here

```
@Column(name = "point", columnDefinition = "POINT")
private Point point;
```

And in my application.properties file, I've Added

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56SpatialDialect
```

While passing a JSON like `"point": "51.61100420, -0.10213410"` I'm getting this error

*> "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.geo.Point` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('(51.61100420, -0.10213410)'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.geo.Point` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('(51.61100420, -0.10213410)')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 11, column: 12]*

Please help me with this, Thanks in advance

Comment: What `Point` class is that?

Comment: @Andreas It is from the package org.springframework.data.geo;

Comment: Because [`Point`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/geo/Point.html) has a `getX()` and a `getY()` method, the default serialized JSON for it is `"point": { "x": 51.61100420, "y": -0.10213410 }`, but deserializing will not work by default for that JSON text, because there are no setter methods. With JSON text `"point": "51.61100420, -0.10213410"`, the default deserializer needs a constructor taking a `String` parameter, and `Point` doesn't have that. You need to provide custom (de)serializers.

Comment: Yeah okay @Andreas ! Thanks